# ImportError pyinstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x

Значит, я пытаюсь сделать из своей .py программки - .exe .
Но когда запускаю `pyinstaller Nothing_here.py`, у меня выходит такая ошибка:

```
  File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
  File "c:\users\╨╕╨╝╤П\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "c:\users\╨╕╨╝╤П\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "c:\users\╨╕╨╝╤П\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "c:\users\╨╕╨╝╤П\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.compat._inspect import getargspec
  File "c:\users\╨╕╨╝╤П\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import py3k
  File "c:\users\╨╕╨╝╤П\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\py3k.py", line 137, in <module>
    os_fspath = os.fspath
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'fspath'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\pkgutil.py", line 485, in find_loader
    spec = importlib.util.find_spec(fullname)
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\importlib\util.py", line 88, in find_spec
    parent = __import__(parent_name, fromlist=['__path__'])
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import core
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\multiarray.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import overrides
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\overrides.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.compat._inspect import getargspec
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from . import py3k
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\numpy\compat\py3k.py", line 137, in <module>
    os_fspath = os.fspath
AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'fspath'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 320, in get_module_file_attribute
    loader = pkgutil.find_loader(package)
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\pkgutil.py", line 491, in find_loader
    raise ImportError(msg.format(fullname, type(ex), ex)) from ex
ImportError: Error while finding loader for 'numpy.core' (<class 'AttributeError'>: module 'os' has no attribute 'fspath')

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\Имя\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe\__main__.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 114, in run
    run_build(pyi_config, spec_file, **vars(args))
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\__main__.py", line 65, in run_build
    PyInstaller.building.build_main.main(pyi_config, spec_file, **kwargs)
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 734, in main
    build(specfile, kw.get('distpath'), kw.get('workpath'), kw.get('clean_build'))
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 681, in build
    exec(code, spec_namespace)
  File "C:\Users\Имя\Desktop\fff\Nothing_here.spec", line 17, in <module>
    noarchive=False)
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 244, in __init__
    self.__postinit__()
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\datastruct.py", line 160, in __postinit__
    self.assemble()
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\building\build_main.py", line 422, in assemble
    self.graph.process_post_graph_hooks()
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\analysis.py", line 311, in process_post_graph_hooks
    module_hook.post_graph()
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 417, in post_graph
    self._load_hook_module()
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\depend\imphook.py", line 384, in _load_hook_module
    self.hook_module_name, self.hook_filename)
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\compat.py", line 797, in importlib_load_source
    return mod_loader.load_module()
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 379, in _check_name_wrapper
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 801, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 660, in load_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 268, in _load_module_shim
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 693, in _load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 656, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\hooks\hook-numpy.core.py", line 29, in <module>
    pkg_base, pkg_dir = get_package_paths('numpy.core')
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 537, in get_package_paths
    file_attr = get_module_file_attribute(package)
  File "c:\users\имя\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\utils\hooks\__init__.py", line 339, in get_module_file_attribute
    raise ImportError
ImportError
```

Вот все модули из моего проекта: `"os", "time", "telebot", "socket", "pyautogui" и "playsound"`

Уже как день пытаюсь это решить.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У Вас русские имена в пути с установленным питоном. Или кривое имя в пути. Это что **╨╕╨╝╤П**?
Переинсталируйте Python например в C:\python\

Избавьтесь полностью от русских путей. Как в самом питоне так и в вашем проекте.

Также, устанавливайте питон только с сайта python.org. Не устанавливайте питон из магазина microsoft (Если Вы так сделали).

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Решил проблему!